# awk delete field if other column match

Tags: csv, vim, awk

i have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,2,a,01/01
2,3,b,01/02
3,4,5,c,01/03
2,5,6,c,01/03
```

The last 2 rows have been appended to the file but it has an extra column (third column). I want to delete the third column from the last 2 rows (i.e. where column 4 == "c" and column 5 == "01/03")

Output i want is to remove the third column from last 2 rows such that it has only 4 columns:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,2,a,01/01
2,3,b,01/02
3,4,c,01/03
2,5,c,01/03
```

if can be done in vim, would be good too

Comment: in vim, you'd type `:%s/,[^,]\+\(,c,01\/03\)$/\1/`

Comment: or even `1,$s/\v(^(\d+,){2})\d+,/\1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {if (NF == 5) {print $1, $2, $4, $5} else {print}}' filename
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly different approach that avoids having to type the list of columns to be included:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} NF==5 {for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){$i=$(i+1)}; NF--} 1'
```

The solution with an explicit listing of columns can also be written more compactly as follows:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} NF == 5 {print $1, $2, $4, $5; next} 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1,$2,$(NF-1),$NF}' file
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,2,a,01/01
2,3,b,01/02
3,4,c,01/03
2,5,c,01/03
```